# Adding <li> to options on node edit and node create screen

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I have an option field on my content types that allows you to select several items in a taxonomy vocabulary. The list has several child and parent items and it is really hard to read.

Is there a way I can add html around these checklist elements so that I can format them better with CSS?

I have attached a screenshot for more info.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Taxonomy Term Reference Tree](https://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) module that will format terms hierarchically.

> This module provides an expandable tree widget for the Taxonomy Term
>   Reference field in Drupal 7. This widget is intended to serve as a
>   replacement for Drupal's core Taxonomy Term Reference widget, which is
>   a flat list of radio buttons or checkboxes and not necessarily fit for
>   medium to large taxonomy trees.

This module produces nested ul lists, which seems optimal for styling hierarchies, if needed.

Comment: Op isn't asking for the structure, but how to add a class around the form element so he can style them.

Comment: I don't see him asking "how to add a class around the form element". He is actually asking how to add html (<li>) around the checklist items and styling that. Those are divs that already have a ton of classes that can be styled, but the initial problem seemed to be that the structure is hard to read. This module might help there.

Comment: Ah...my mistake! Sorry, I hadn't read the module page properly!

Comment: I've formatted the answer mainly so I could turn my downvote upside down :)

Comment: This is perfect. Keep it simple, less coding for me the better the solution. Thanks